# Adding sum to first of duplicated rows, with zero/nil in subsequent duplicated rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table that compares last years transactions per customer, to this years transactions for the same customer. These are in different currencies. Below is a replica of the query I am running:

```
select distinct Customer ID, b.[Last Year Trans. Date], b.[Last year Trans. ID], b.[Last Year Curr.], b.[Last year Sales],transactiondate as 'Current Trans. Date',transactionid as 'Current Trans. ID',currency AS 'Current Curr.',sum(salesamount) AS 'Current Sales'
from Customer
full join Sales
on (PolicyNumber = Policy_Number and CurrencyOriginalCode = Original_Currency_Code)
full outer join
(select distinct customerID, transactiondate as 'Last Year Trans. Date', transactionid as 'Last year Trans. ID' ,currency AS 'Last Year Curr.', sum(salesamount) AS 'Last year Sales'
from sales
join customer
on CUSTOMER ID = CUSTOMERID
group by customer ID , transactiondate, transactionid,currency) as b
on b.customerID = Customer ID
where  b.[Sales] != 0
group by Customer ID, b.[Last Year Trans. Date], b.[Last year Trans. ID], b.[Last Year Curr.], b.[Last year Sales],transactiondate,transactionid,currency
order by b.[Last year Trans. ID]
```

The output I am getting is as follows (just one row as an example)

| Customer ID | Last year Trans. Date | Last year Trans. ID | Last Year Curr. | Last year Sales | Current Trans. Date | Current Trans. ID | Current Curr. | Current Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 1234 | GBP | 2000 | 01/01/2021 | 1235 | GBP | 1000 |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 1234 | GBP | 2000 | 01/01/2021 | 1235 | USD | 500 |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 1234 | GBP | 2000 | 01/01/2021 | 1235 | EUR | 1000 |

What would like to see is:

| Customer ID | Last year Trans. Date | Last year Trans. ID | Last Year Curr. | Last year Sales | Current Trans. Date | Current Trans. ID | Current Curr. | Current Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 1234 | GBP | 2000 | 01/01/2021 | 1235 | GBP | 1000 |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 1234 | GBP | 0 | 01/01/2021 | 1235 | USD | 500 |
| 123 | 01/01/2020 | 1234 | GBP | 0 | 01/01/2021 | 1235 | EUR | 1000 |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL doesn't have `[]`, so it must be Microsoft.